# Ember.js: Passing a template's current context object to an action

Tags: ember.js

I'm working on an Ember.js app similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rzb2m/

Now this does pretty much what I want except for one crucial problem.  The `setFavorite` action at the bottom has a hard-coded 0.  This means that if you change Carol's favorite activity, it actually changes Alice's favorite activity.  I haven't been able to figure out how to structure the application so that it has the correct behavior.  How do I pass the correct object to be changed (this.content.people[i] in this case) to the setFavorite function?

Note: My real application is actually a bit more complicated than this because I have two separate lists of people on the page.  So the solution shouldn't just involve passing an index into setFavorite because that won't scale to the more complex situation with multiple lists.  This is also why the person template looks unused.  In the real app, there is complexity that justifies it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are relying on implicit binding resolution from controllers to views. But this breaks down because when you separate things out into partials you have no means to lookup the parent object in the `#each` iteration.

While `#each controller` works, you are better off with `#each person in controller`. Then you can access the properties from the `view` in the partial view, and pass it forward as needed.

Change the main `#each` in `index` template to,

```
{{#each person in people}}
  <li>{{view App.PersonView contentBinding=person}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Then in `person template`,

```
{{view App.PersonDetailsView contentBinding=view.content}}
```

And in `personDetails` template.

```
{{#each fave in view.content.getActivities}}
```

All this gives you the ability to pass the person to the `setFavorite` method,

```
<a {{action setFavorite view.content fave}} href="#">
```

So the `setFavorite` switches to a simple assignment on that person.

```
setFavorite: function(person, fave) {
  person.set('favoriteActivity', fave.name);
},
```

Here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMCBc/).